# Adding a custom template?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have modified a template TFS (Scrum), with dowload held in:

*Settings-> Process Template Manager*

As shown below.

[image]

I'm editing this Template in: *Tools-> Process Editor-> Work Item Types-> Open WIT from file.*

Now I would like to add this Template in my visual studio, or when I add a *New Work Item Product Backlog Item*, it appears customized according to what I define.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/22817.alm-como-editar-work-items-e-process-template-do-tfs-work-item.aspx) to the template editing.

Comment: Are you using on-premise TFS or Visual Studio Team Service?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT visual studio Community 2015.

Comment: I mean which version of TFS are you using, not VS? Are you using on-premise TFS or Visual Studio Team Service (https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/)?

Comment: The tutorial you are referring to is for on-premise TFS, not for VSTS. You need confirm you are using on-premise TFS or Visual Studio Team Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't upload the process template, I assume you are using Visual Studio Team Service.

If so, you need to follow article [Customize a process](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/customize-process) to do the customization. For example, you want to add a custom WIT, try go to the admin Process page, create an inherited process (You can only customize inherited processes), and then add new work item type. [See here for more information](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/customize-process-wit#add-a-work-item-type).

[image]

Comment: The Work Item inherited can not be modified? I would like to edit for example the Work Item Product Backlog.

Comment: For each work item type, you can add, modify, move or remove custom fields, groups and pages. And you can also modify the attributes of an inherited field, group or page as well as hide inherited fields. Learn more: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/customize-process-field

Comment: Thanks for the likes and response.